# SQL Server 2005 64 bit

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, 64-bit, windows-7-x64

i have windows 7 64 bit. I have installed SQL Server 2005 32 bit in it. it installed properly but the native clients says its not proper or compatible to run in x64 mode.My question: Where can i get native client that can be run on 64 bit OR Is SQL Server 2005 there for 64 bit?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, SQL Server 2005 runs fine as a 32-bit app under WOW64.

There is also a [64-bit optimised version](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/64-bit.aspx) available.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but i guess Microsoft has stopped giving trial version of SQL 05 after 08.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install [64 bit Native Client](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=DF0BA5AA-B4BD-4705-AA0A-B477BA72A9CB&displaylang=en). The server will work, but OLEDB tends to behave incorrectly when 32bit version is used on 64bit operating system.

Comment: I think you mean "when 32 bit version is used from a 64 bit process"

Comment: i got a solution to this where you need to install SQL Server 2005 SP3 which is for Windows 7. I did that but i didn't got Management Studio Interface (In win 7). It installed great in Win XP SP2.